# Web Share API not working with Github pages

Tags: service-worker, github-pages

I am trying to implement the share button using the Web Share API,
The website is deployed on Github Pages.

Here is my share button code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      if(!navigator.share) {
        document.querySelector('.share-container').innerHTML = 'Web Share API not supported in this browser';
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('btn-share').addEventListener('click', function() {
        navigator.share({
          title: '',
          text: "{{ page.title }}".
          url: "{{ site.baseurl }}/",
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Do I need to add a service-worker.js file ??
Because that's not working too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an issue with using on GitHub pages as it works fine for me - see here: https://mkonikov.com/web-share-testing/
Source: https://github.com/mkonikov/web-share-testing

I would try adding a `catch` block and console out the error to see what may be causing.

You can see a code example here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share